# ADF deployment is failing if the ADF objects are renamed

Tags: ansible, azure-data-factory, ansible-role

We've have renamed our ADF pipelines in the code and tried deploying them using "`-role: ansible-role-azure-adf-deploy`" role. But, the build is failing as it fails to delete the existing ADF objects. I've tried using the parameter "`azure_adf_max_delete_retries: 2`", yet the old ADF objects are not deleted. Is there any other way instead of deleting the ADF instance manually ?
Following is a log URL for your reference :

https://dev.azure.com/chevron/CGM-ST-Pond/_build/results?buildId=1184234&view=logs&j=0dfcbfa6-5050-52a7-7298-8f7d8bed78bb&t=9d2bf12b-b622-5483-377c-729016318825

Could someone help ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear ( the link does not take you anywhere ) , but i think you are trying to deploy a ADF using ansible and AFAIK that this is not supported  . Please do let me know as to how you initially deployed the ADF ?